# How to write to a txt file "using the keyboard and PrintWriter Class " created in java

Tags: java

I created a method for writing to a file but the method could not  execute as I called it in the main method. I also want to find what to know if I can write to the file via keyboard instead of using the PrintWriter resource?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
/**
 *
 * @author toshiba
 */
public  class EXERISESONFILEWRITINGANDREADING {
        File file;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        EXERISESONFILEWRITINGANDREADING obj = new   EXERISESONFILEWRITINGANDREADING();
        obj.Create("D:\\document\\work.txt");
        obj.Write();
        obj.Read();
        }

    public  void Create(String name){ //name implies the directory of your  folder/file.
         file = new File(name); 
    }

    public void Write() throws Exception{
        PrintWriter WRITE = new PrintWriter(file);
        WRITE.print("this is my abode");
        WRITE.print("\nthis is my apartment");
        WRITE.print("\nthis is my Private Jet");
    }
    public void Read() throws Exception{
        Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
        while(input.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(input.next());
        }
    }
```

Comment: use `Scanner(System.in)` to read `String`s from the console, that lines then can be written to the `PrinterWriter` instead of the constants

Comment: @ArtemFedotov 'Correct code style' is one thing: changing the OP's variable names is quite another. Edit rejected.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not executing because, you are not flushing your `PrintWriter` resource in your `write` method. Your `write` method will write to a given file you change it to this:

```
public void write() throws Exception {
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(file);
    writer.println("this is my abode");
    writer.println("this is my apartment");
    writer.println("this is my Private Jet");

    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
}
```

Now, if you want to accept inputs from keyboard and then write it to file, you can make use of `Scanner`.

Create a `Scanner` with `System.in` as `InputStream`:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Create or use your same `PrintWriter` resource:

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(file);
```

Start accepting the inputs from the keyboard until the user gives in a blank line - "" and write it to your file.

```
String in = "";
while ( !(in = sc.nextLine()).equals("") ) {
    writer.println(in);
}
```

And finally, the entire method should look like:

```
public void writeToFileFromKeyboard() throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(file);

    String in = "";
    while ( !(in = sc.nextLine()).equals("") ) {
        writer.println(in);
    }

    sc.close();
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
}
```

**Note:** **This is just a suggestion!!**

If you are using **Java-8**, you can modify your `read()` method to make use of Java-8 Streams, so that your method becomes more [declarative in nature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declarative_programming). Hence, the modified `read()`method looks like:

```
public void read() throws Exception {
    Files.lines( Paths.get(filePath) )
         .forEach( System.out::println );
}
```